# Typescript Interface for Recharts Custom Tooltip

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, tooltip, recharts

Being not well-versed with Typescript yet, I am trying to [create a custom Tooltip content](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip) for my Recharts chart in my React app with Typescript. `@types/recharts` has already been installed as one of the a `devDependencies`.

However, when I define the `CustomTooltip` function as shown below, Typescript is throwing an error

> Binding element 'active' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

How can we solve this issue?

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
    if (active) {
        return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip">
            <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
            <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        </div>
        );
    }

    return null;
}

return (
    <ComposedChart data={data}>
        ...
        <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
    </ComposedChart>
)
```

---

Tried defining an interface, but got another error

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ICustomToolip': active, payload, label  TS2739

```
interface ICustomToolip {
    active: any;
    payload: any;
    label: any;
}

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: ICustomToolip) => {
    if (active) {
        return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip">
            <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
            <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        </div>
        );
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to do the following (using rechart's types).

```js
import { TooltipProps } from 'recharts';
// for recharts v2.1 and above
import {
    ValueType,
    NameType,
} from 'recharts/types/component/DefaultTooltipContent';
// for recharts versions below v2.1
import {
    ValueType,
    NameType,
} from 'recharts/src/component/DefaultTooltipContent';

const CustomTooltip = ({
    active,
    payload,
    label,
}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if (active) {
    return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload?.[0].value}`}</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        </div>
    );
    }

    return null;
};

return (
    <ComposedChart data={data}>
    ...
    <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
    </ComposedChart>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed to resolve my type errors.

Comment: import { NameType, ValueType } from 'recharts/types/component/DefaultTooltipContent';

Need to import types from this path with version 2.5.0

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: TooltipProps<number, string>): JSX.Element => {
```

Change number and string to your data types. You can also use it with the ValueType and NameType, but it makes more sense to declare it with your types.

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>): JSX.Element => {
```

Answer (score 3):

@Daria Babakova's answer almost covers it, but the only thing to note - is that you shouldn't import from "src".

So, instead of

```
import {
  ValueType,
  NameType,
} from 'recharts/src/component/DefaultTooltipContent';
```

better to write

```
import {
  ValueType,
  NameType,
} from 'recharts/types/component/DefaultTooltipContent';
```

at least on recharts 2.1.12 it works well.

Answer (score 2):

usually

```
TooltipProps<number, string>
```

but depends on you graph data, so generically

```
TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that may help people. I'm using typescript btw. I did this without an explicit interface, just an any type like so.

```
                `{ 
                    'time': item.DateTime.getTime(),
                    'data': 1,
                    'change_type': "some_string",
                }`
```

In your TSX, make sure to pass in undefined like so. The example on the website was fine without explicitly saying that, but my editor complained about some error. `<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip active={undefined} payload={undefined} label={undefined}/>} />`

For CustomToolTip, this was tricky for me to understand. The payload has to have index of 0. Then call dot operator as there's a payload class there to access your custom properties like time, data, and change_type

```
    const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
    if (active && payload && payload.length) {
      return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip">
          <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].payload.time}`}</p>
          <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].payload.data}`}</p>
          <p className="label">{`${payload[0].payload.change_type}`}</p>
          <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  
    return null;
  };
```

Then it should pop up in correctly without any issues on hover.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const CustomTooltip = ({
  active,
  payload,
  label,
}: {
  active: boolean;
  label: string;
  payload: {
    payload: {
      value: number
    }
  }[];
}) => {
  if (active) {
    return ( <
      div className = "custom-tooltip" >
      <
      p className = "label" > {
        `${label} : ${payload[0].value}`
      } < /p> <
      p className = "desc" > Anything you want can be displayed here. < /p> <
      /div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};

return ( <
  ComposedChart data = {
    data
  } >
  ...
  <
  Tooltip content = { < CustomTooltip active = {
      false
    }
    payload = {
      []
    }
    label = "" / >
  }
  /> <
  /ComposedChart>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

It usually works for me,but other way could be:

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: any) => {
```