# Customized Typescript Interface for Recharts Custom Tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I am trying to add some more data to my customized Tooltip other than the data available by default. Now, I want to write a type for such a tooltip, already seen one of the solutions which has not passed anything else other than the props which recharts chart internally passes to the custom tooltip.

The solution I am referring to above: [Typescript Interface for Recharts Custom Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913461/typescript-interface-for-recharts-custom-tooltip)

my code:
`<Tooltip   content={   <CustomToolTipComponent     detailsType={detailsType}     selectedItemUnit={selectedItemUnit}   />   } />`

I am using this tooltip for a Line Chart.

I tried searching for more solutions to it but can't find anything on recharts documentation and on any other platforms till now. The solution I mentioned above provides the inbuilt type for the collection of data passed to the Tooltip by default but doesn't give scope to add any other data type to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a new type which extends the TooltipProps type to include your inputs.

```js
import { TooltipProps } from 'recharts';
import { ValueType, NameType } from 'recharts/src/component/DefaultTooltipContent';

declare type MyTooltip<MyValue extends ValueType, MyName extends NameType> = 
TooltipProps<MyValue, MyName> & {
  detailsType: string;
  selectedItemUnit: object;
};

const CustomTooltip = ({active, payload, label, detailsType, selectedItemUnit}: MyTooltip<ValueType, NameType>) => {};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I cannot confirm if this works or not now, since I have switched from my firm and therefore do not have access to that code. But this can be helpful to others.