# Adding typing to custom xaxis tick component with recharts

Tags: typescript, recharts

I get this message when trying to add a custom xaxis tick component in recharts:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from '{x: number; y: number; payload: {value: number}}': x, y, payload
```

I've found examples for other custom components ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913461/typescript-interface-for-recharts-custom-tooltip), [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729339/customized-typescript-interface-for-recharts-custom-tooltip)), but was unable to figure out how to apply those solutions to a custom tick component. Any ideas how to get rid of the message?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Text,
} from 'recharts';


const CustomXAxisTick = ({x, y, payload}: {x: number, y: number, payload: {value: number}) => {
  if (payload && payload.value) {
    return (
      <Text
        x={x}
        y={y}
        ...other stuff
      >
        {payload.value}
      </Text>
    )
..}
}

export const Chart = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={300}>
      <BarChart>
        <XAxis dataKey='x' tick={<CustomXAxisTick />} /> <--- error message here
      <BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the approach from [this example](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart) work for you?

Comment: @kikon My code works. The problem is the typescript warning that I get when I don't pass any props to my custom component. I'm trying to figure out the proper way to add typing to my custom component so the message doesn't show.

Comment: The link I gave in the previous message was also typed, I thought it might be an idiomatic solution. To make your code be accepted by typescript you may follow the example of `TooltipProps` and make all the properties in the the type of the argument optional (i.e., `{x, y, payload}: {x?: number, y?: number, payload?: ...}`), or, *in extremis*, even skip typing altogether, (i.e., `{x, y, payload}: any`)